# Change AnimationClip's sprites in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

So I have an Animator, which animates my player when moving, I have a SpriteRenderer property in my AnimationClip with a few frames. If the player gets an upgrade I want the animation to behave the same, but change these sprites. How is is that possible? (I'd prefer to do it programmatically.)

**Edit**: please note that I can't just create a new animation state to achieve this, cause if I have 3 SpriteRenderer property in an animation, each of these refers to a part of the character, each part can be upgraded 4 times, so If I create different animation states for each possible combination, I end up with 5^3 animations.

[image]

Comment: `Behave the same but change these sprites` in what way do you mean? Like a different colour, but the same running animation, or something completely different?

Comment: I want to change the sprites, as you can see there are other properties (Rotation, dirt.isActive), I want them to remain the same.

Comment: hi Ference -- what's the problem?  **Duplicate** the animation, and make a slightly different one.  Just change between the two animations.  No issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically change the sprites in `LateUpdate()`. I've never done this myself, but there seems to be an explanation in this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMCLWt1DuqI) at about 20 mins in.

He switches out the spritesheets based on a string which corresponds to a set of sprites. Look for the section called "ReSkinAnimation" (23:00) if you are skipping through.

Comment: Yeah I've found this video as well, the problem here is, that he directly accesses the components of the character's GameObject and it's children, and change their Renderer's sprite. But I want to access my Animator's **DrillHrizontal** AnimationClip, and change the sprites of the keyframes.

Comment: LateUpdate ??  never use LateUpdate.  certainly don't use it here, Tom

Comment: for goodness sake, just make different animations and have your state machine choose the right one at the right time

Comment: Sorry @JoeBlow - I've just taken that from the code in the video - if it's not recommended then I agree with you :)

Comment: I also agree, I think your intended method is far too complicated for what you want, just simplify and change states.

Comment: OK for one animation property. But if I have 3 SpriteRenderer property in an animation, each of these refers to a part of the character, each part can be upgraded 4 times, so If I create different animations for each possible combination, I end up with 5^3 animations.